# Mouse Click vs Enter Frame Stage reference

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a document class with some constructor code. I have two event listeners in the constructor. One of them is an enter frame listener and the other is a mouse click listener. The enter frame function moves a rectangle on the stage. The mouse event function removes it from the stage when its been clicked.

When I used the following:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkTarget);
```

The rectangle didn't get removed. But when I used:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkTarget);
```

It worked fine. I kept the enter frame without referencing the stage and it worked.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
```

Why did the mouse click need the reference to the stage and the enter frame didn't? Aren't they both added to the same thing at the same time?

Comment: Doing the addEventListener without stage is adding the event listener to whatever `this` refers to. So my guess would be that `this` has an area smaller than the whole stage and isn't getting clicked on in the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mouse event needs something to work with but ENTER_FRAME is built to work with stage.
I would change the mouse event listener to listen to when you clicked at a mc just like that rectangle if I where you.